# Incorrect datatip label during slow datacursormode callback

Tags: matlab, callback, matlab-figure, datatip

It is fairly easy to add a custom datatip

```
f = figure();
plot( 1:100, sort(rand(100,1)) );
dc = datacursormode( f );
set( dc, 'UpdateFcn', @onDataCursorUpdate );

function txt = onDataCursorUpdate( tip, evt )
    txt = {sprintf( 'X: %g', tip.Position(1) ), ...
           sprintf( 'Y: %g', tip.Position(2) )};
end
```

But the update function might take a while to fetch the datatip info.

In my case, the data I want to include in `txt` has to be fetched from a database query. I realise that this is inefficient from a performance standpoint, but it is much more memory efficient than storing all possible datatip attributes in memory!

```
function txt = onDataCursorUpdate( tip, evt )
    info = mySlowQuery( tip.Position ); % fetch some data about this point
    txt = {sprintf( 'X: %g', tip.Position(1) ), ...
           sprintf( 'Y: %g', tip.Position(2) ), ...
           sprintf( 'Info: %s', info )};
end
```

This query may take minutes(!), and unfortunately MATLAB updates the position of the datatip before updating the label, so you can end up with the following sequence of events:

[image: issue]

**Is there a way to prevent this happening, so there is no period when the label is incorrect?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly interact with the datatip at the start of the callback to clear the label, then run the body of the callback. The output `txt` still automatically gets assigned to the datatip `String` property, but you can manually change it earlier in the function:

```
function txt = onDataCursorUpdate( tip, evt )
    % Clear the string first, use "loading..." as placeholder text
    txt = {sprintf( 'X: %g', tip.Position(1) ), ...
           sprintf( 'Y: %g', tip.Position(2) ), ...
           'Info: loading...'};
    tip.String = txt;
    % Now run the slow update
    info = mySlowQuery( tip.Position ); % fetch some data about this point
    txt = {sprintf( 'X: %g', tip.Position(1) ), ...
           sprintf( 'Y: %g', tip.Position(2) ), ...
           sprintf( 'Info: %s', info )};
end
```